# longtable: how to avoid duplicated midrules below table title?

Tags: longtable, rules

I want to typeset a longtable which is structured by `midrules`, as the rows are divided in groups.

If it happens (which is in general desirable!) that a group is not split by a page break, in other words a new page of the table starts with a new group, I have duplicated `midrules` as there is one from the headline definition and one from the table code.

See following example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}

\begin{document}

here comes the table with the pagebreak

\vspace{0.6\textheight}



\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}l}

\toprule
A & B & C & D\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\mbox{table continued from last page}\\
\toprule
A & B & C & D\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\mbox{to be continued on following page}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
 a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
 a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
\midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Questions:

- Is there a way to make `LaTeX` automatically ignore a second `midrule`?
- another way could be to define the table *head* without `midrule` and only allow pagebreaks before the `midrules` - how could I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disallow page breaking in your groups together with `\midrule` following them, put `*` after each `\\`. i.e. use `\\*`.

It requires removing `\bottomrule` in foot (the one after `\endhead` and before `\endfoot`), because otherwise you'll get two rules at the end of table on each non-last page.

Comment: thank you. This is however _not_ what I want, as the midrules separate groups of rows and it would be desirable to split the table _at_ the midrules! (but without showing them).

Comment: @Martin: I've updated the answer. Sorry, I somehow missed the grouping part and focused on preserving `\midrule` on the current page, because I had similar problem some time ago, but I was using `\midrule` after each row and that is why I gave you wrong solution at first.

Comment: @Martin: Once again updated. Well, Herbert provided `\\*` before me, but I found it independently checking `longtable` doc. I am really ashamed that previously when I was solving similar problem myself I didn't noticed the `\\*` part...

Comment: no need to be ashamed!! Thank you very much for this elegant and easy solution (I did not know about the star version `\\*` and it makes thinks very easy, as in those tables with grouped rows I just have to replace `\\` by `\\*` and let the ˚\midrules` allow pagebreaks.

Comment: sorry, there is some typo in my last comment: I wanted to say " replace \\ by \\\* "

Comment: one question is still open (I had overlooked it in my enthusiasm): your solution only allows pagebreaks after groups, which is desirable but not always possible (if some groups are very long and would leave much white space on the bottom of the last page). But if I leave out the star, my table ends with a row and no midrule. Would it be possible to really avoid duplicated rules if they occur (or have a condition which only adds a midrule if there is not already one below the last row)?

Comment: @Martin: It's not your typo, it's screwed markdown parsing within backticks, which is problematic only in comments. `\\`

Comment: @Martin: I am not aware of any intelligent rule. Just never leave out star in the last line of group. If you want to allow breaking, then do it somewhere before. `\midrule` means end of row group and you should stick to this, i.e. do not leave "open" table unless the row group is not finished. Otherwise you impede proper reading of your table.